# On click, hide div and remove required attribute

Tags: jquery, html, input, attributes

I have a form that can appear on different pages, and depending on the circumstance, the fields are not always required.

I have the code to hide the div, but need the input fields to no longer be required. Using the HTML5 Required attribute. Having trouble getting the code to work. Code is below:

```
$('#detailssame').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(\"#detailssamehide\").hide();
    } else {
        $(\"#detailssamehide\").show();
    }               
});
$('.fullboxform input[type=text], .fullboxform select').each(function() {
            $(this).removeAttr('required');
});
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Turns out the above code does work correctly, but alternative answer available using prop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use the [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function for setting HTML5 properties.

```
$(function () {
    $('#detailssame').click(function() {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        if(checked) {
            $("#detailssamehide").hide();
        } else {
            $("#detailssamehide").show();
        }     
        $('.fullboxform input[type=text], .fullboxform select').each(function() {
            $(this).prop('required', !checked);
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ThsXU/

Comment: According to my readings, setting ``prop('required', false)`` does NOT reliably remove the required status in all browsers. You MUST use ``removeAttr('required')`` for stable results in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the backslashes was enough for me to run your code with desired effect.

Comment: The slashes were in there as it is output by PHP. You are correct it did run. Just checked further with console and didn't realise I had a couple of required inputs that were not text.

Comment: Try not to output js in PHP, since it prevents caching and is easier to muddle up and harder to maintain. Most importantly, avoid putting code from one language into another language's string.